# Покажите как пользоваться динамическими массивами perl

Tags: perl, динамические-массивы

Программа падает. Вот в таком варианте падает. Как нужно?

```
    $N = 1;
@KonstruktorRjadkiv = ([59][$N]);
                     for($U=0;$U<=58;$U++)  
                            { 
                                @KonstruktorRjadkiv [$U][$N-1]= ('|!    Немає значення     ');
                                @KonstruktorRjadkiv [58][$N-1]= ('|!    Немає значення  |  '. "\n";);
                            }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Твой `for`можно переписать как `for (0..58)` и использовать внутри цикла переменную `$_`, содержащую **текущее** значение (вместо `$U`). Так же всегда используй в начале скрипта **`use strict`** и **`use warnings`**. Это укажет на некоторые проблемы в твоём коде

Answer (score 1):

В perl все массивы динамические. Заранее резервировать место в них или объявлять их многомерными не надо. Как таковых многомерных массивов в perl вроде как и нет вовсе. Многомерный массив в perl это такой массив все элементы которого содержат другие массивы. Но никто не мешает при этом сделать массив первым элементом которого будет другой массив, вторым элементом строка (т.е. скаляр), а третьим вообще хеш.

Ваш пример можно было бы записать так:

```
my $N = 1;
my @KonstruktorRjadkiv = ();  # Создаем пустой массив
for($U=0;$U<=58;$U++) {    # заполняем 59 элементов массивами из одного элемента со строкой
 $KonstruktorRjadkiv [$U][$N-1]='|!    Нет значения     ';
}
$KonstruktorRjadkiv [58][$N-1]='|!    Нет значения  |  '."\n";
```

Как видите мы вообще не говорили, что массив двумерный, но при его заполнении спокойно обратились ко второму измерению, при этом perl автоматически создал вложенный массив и присвоил значение его первому элементу.

Обратите внимание: при обращении к конкретному элементу массива мы пишем перед его именем `$`, потому что отдельный элемент массива всегда скаляр ! `@` мы используем только когда хотим обратится к массиву целиком или к срезу массива (набору элементов).

Для $N=1 ваш пример так же можно записать следующим образом:

```
my @KonstruktorRjadkiv;
for($U=0;$U<=58;$U++) {
 $KonstruktorRjadkiv[$U]=[ '|!    Нет значения     ' ];
}
$KonstruktorRjadkiv[58][0]='|!    Нет значения  |  '."\n";
```

Как видите внутри цикла мы явно присвоили элементу массива вновь создаваемый массив из одного элемента.

Или вообще так:

```
my @KonstruktorRjadkiv = map { ['|!    Нет значения     '] } (0..58); # заполняем 59 элементов
$KonstruktorRjadkiv[58][0].="\n"; # И добавляем перевод каретки в последний
```